# Googlebot stays on site for a very long time

Tags: javascript, php, googlebot

I have a javascript timer that does an ajax call to a php database application that updates a database every couple of minutes. The javascript runs continuously and updates the database. I have seen googlebot sitting on the same file for over 12 hours. What are they doing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243718/php-code-to-exclude-google

Comment: Are you sure your code is correct?

Comment: *"What are they doing?"* - No idea. Probably up to no good and wanting to blow your server, who knows.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Code, what code? *arf*

Comment: @Fred-ii- This magic javascript that keeps an eye on the world as it passes by his site

Comment: @RiggsFolly You mean "soyt", right? Moy Oyrish is a bit roosty.

Comment: GoogleBot doesn't execute JavaScript on your site, so it doesn't "sit" anywhere — Google fetches the file, processes it, and moves on.

Comment: @VoteyDisciple Thats probably the most relevant comment so far